# Way to get parts of a text with php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Hi I search a simple way to get parts of a Text like this:

```
Playtech Ltd., London (Teststreet 3, 1234 London, Sale all interesting things.). Directors: Paul, Test, London, *01.01.1900; Lisa, Test, London, *01.01.1901.
```

I want to have this:

```
firm: Playtech Ltd.
street: Teststreet 3
postcode: 1234
city: London
sale: Sale all interesting things.
directors: Paul, Test, London, *01.01.1900; Lisa, Test, London, *01.01.1901
```

Sometimes there is an other Format:

For example:

```
ABC 12345:Playtech Ltd., London (Teststreet 3, 1234 London). A Firm. Sale: Sale all interesting things. Directors: Paul, Test, London, *01.01.1900; Lisa, Test, London, *01.01.1901.
```

Is there a possibility to make it with php? Because I must do it for 5.000 Texts.

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: Ad the moment I have no good idea. Perhaps I can try something like this:

$regex = '/Directors: (.*)./';
$code = preg_match($regex, $node->nodeValue, $matches);

But I don't think it is the best way.

Comment: Is there only these 2 formats?

Comment: No there are also some other formats. Like Director: sometimes called Board of Directors: and so but the other I think is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match :

```
^(?:.*?:)?(.*?),\s*.*?\((.*?),\s*(\d+)\s*(.*?),\s*(.*?)\)\.\s*.*?(?:(?:Board of )?Directors):\s*(.*)$
```

And replace with / extract out:

```
firm: $1\nstreet: $2\npostcode: $3\ncity: $4\nsale: $5\ndirectors: \6\n
```

**Output:**

```
firm: Playtech Ltd.
street: Teststreet 3
postcode: 1234
sale: Sale all interesting things.
directors: Paul, Test, London, *01.01.1900; Lisa, Test, London, *01.01.1901.
```

See [updated DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gD3vX4/2)

Comment: I tested it now with your solution:

Test Ltd., London (test Straße 3, 12345 London, distribution of food and all kinds of goods in the retail sector). General partnership. The Company will be represented by two Managing Partners. Directors: Max, Tester, * 22.01.1977.

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Have I done something wrong? https://regex101.com/r/gD3vX4/3 For example I get no match - 372 steps

Comment: I assumed all your patterns will start with something like `ABC 12345:` like you said in your question.. in the updated regex i made it optional.. and also added directors description..

Comment: Ok what I must do if there is also a text behind the directors? For example:

Comment: Paul, Test, London, *01.01.1900; Lisa, Test, London, *01.01.1901, on behalf of the company with himself in his own name or as representatives of a third legal transactions - with the authority - also for the respective directors.

Comment: Yes all work good but...
directors: Max, Tester, * 22.01.1977. This is a Testtext. Or, an other text behind the director.

Comment: i dint get you.. can you give sample where the regex fails?

Comment: ABC 56345:Playtech Ltd., London (Teststreet 3, 1234 London). A Firm. Sale: Sale all interesting things. Test: Paul, Test, London, *01.01.1900; Lisa, Test, London, *01.01.1901.     is also not working

Comment: Isn't there an other way?

Comment: Your patterns does not follow a specific format.. how do you expect to match all formats with single regex? you have to update your question with your possible formats..